# Oracle SQL: Merge some rows with specific same columns

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have a table set in this way:

```
  ID_VENDOR  ISBN            TYPE_ID   AMOUNT  PRICE
> 6317       9788807884245   2001      2       2,99
> 6317       9788808148070   2001      2       8,99
```

I want that every time I add a row with same ID_VENDOR, ISBN AND TYPE_ID, the two rows as in this example:

```
6317      9788808148070    2001    2     8,99
6317      9788808148070    2001    1     7,99
```

will be merged like in a unique row like this:

```
6317      9788808148070    2001    3     7,99
```

Where the AMOUNT will be summed and the PRICE will be update with the last price inserted. If, for example, I insert more than two rows in this way:

```
6317      9788808148070    2001    2     8,99
6317      9788808148070    2001    1     7,99
6317      9788808148070    2001    3     7,50
```

These three rows will be merged like this

```
6317      9788808148070    2001    6     7,50
```

I've tried with "MERGE", but it gives me some troubles with duplicates. How can I do?

Comment: See database normalization, you can't store aggregated values in your tables.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a fairly straightforward merge:

```
merge into books b
using (select 6317 as id_vendor, 9788808148070 as isbn, 2001 as type_id,
  1 as amount, 7.99 as price from dual) n
on (n.id_vendor = b.id_vendor and n.isbn = b.isbn and n.type_id = b.type_id)
when matched then
update set b.amount = b.amount + n.amount, b.price = n.price
when not matched then
insert (id_vendor, isbn, type_id, amount, price)
values (n.id_vendor, n.isbn, n.type_id, n.amount, n.price);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6fde5/1) with the initial population and all subsequent changes done with the same `merge`, just changing the fixed values.

Not sure why duplicates were giving you trouble; unless maybe your existing data already had multiple rows for the same value? If that is the case then you'd need to clean up the existing data before starting to use this, such that each `vendor_id`, `isbn` and `type_id` combination is unique. That wouldn't error though, it would just give you the wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you just want to do an UPDATE. Why INSERT and then try to aggregate the data? It seems overly complicated.

```
UPDATE vendor_table
SET amount = amount + new_amount,
    price = new_price
WHERE id_vendor = my_vendor_id
      isbn = my_isbn
      type_id = my_type_id;
```

This assumes that you only start with one row per `id_vendor`, `isbn` and `type_id`. Perhaps make this a unique index on your table?

Comment: No, it's not just an UPDATE. It's a particular case in which someone insert a book with the same vendor and the same type. Instead of apply a constraint that deny the inserting, it "merges" the inserted row into the other row with same id_vendor, same isbn and same type_id, setting amount and price in the way that I showed previously.

Comment: What if altogether a new record comes? Neither it will update nor insert, according to this logic.

Comment: True, in which case, it would be a MERGE statement, like the answer below.